# Change Android wear weather to Celsius?

Tags: android, wear-os, weather

How do I change the temperature to 'Celsius' on android weather native app?

There is not much around for this particular issue so, I decided to post my own solution.

Comment: where is this solution?

Comment: This should be in the Android forums and really isn't even a programming question there. @marco's answer does work, and is the answer that is scattered around the rest of the internet.

Comment: Care to cite a resource that states that I'm wrong? By the way - you are definitely in the wrong website. Here's where you need to be.

https://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming-related question.

Answer (score 31):

I know it sounds very straight forward but it's quite hidden.

You need to set your language to english (UK) on your Android device.

```
Settings > Language & Input > Language
```

Android wear app should display the temperature in Celsius.

Comment: Yes, this works.... and works as well for other country which is using Celsius, e.g. English(Singapore)

Comment: There is no 'language and input' option in Sony smart watch 3

Comment: @MohsenKashi You need to set your language to english (UK) on your Android device (phone). Not on your smart watch ;)

Comment: Not working anymore since latest updates apparently.

Comment: This worked for my new Huawei Watch 2, while the other answer didn't. Would love an "Irish English" option though, with all the right metric settings...

Comment: worked for my polar m600 with android wear 2.0

Comment: Works for LG Watch Sport (Android wear 2)

Comment: Woah, it works! really thanks :)

Comment: Works on Wear OS 2.12

Answer (score 5):

1. On your phone, in the Google search bar type "Weather"
2. Weather shows up in say Celcius
3. Switch it once to F and then back to C
4. Open weather on your watch and let it refresh
5. Will show in Celcius

Comment: This worked for me (LG G Watch R and Moto G 2)! Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Wear 2.0 :(

Comment: Not working for me too, on Wear 2.0 (LG Watch Urbane)